# Restrict users permission in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I've a requirement, where I need to add a few users from the UI. I'm working with "developer" access to the project in GitLab. Even if already a few users are added with different access while the project is created and only users added from the UI to perform developer role without making any changes in the project.

Is it possible and how to implement it?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to add new Members to the Project/Group but only have Developer access?

Comment: @st0ph Hi, The need is , only users are adding from UI can perform commits (already added in project / groups ) other all users already added with permission in  while creating project / group should not. like pre-commit. is it possible ?

Comment: Let me try and rephrase that because it still is unclear to me: Only newly added users can perform commits to the project but existing ones are not allowed anymore?

Comment: @st0ph - sorry my bad. In a clear way, existing users and access remains same in gitlab portal. but I need to override it, and only users added from the separate UI can only perform commits. is it possible ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Overwriting" permissions is not possible and if you want to simulate this behavior you could create a new group and share this project with another group. Then you would need to deny access to individual group members. [See this permission matrix.](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/permissions/permissions.html)

Comment: Thanks. so what about restricting few users ? under a project , from a list of users , I need to restrict few users (even if they have developer access) from committing ?

Comment: You can't restrict Developers from pushing other than protecting a branch. It's either all or nothing for Developers.

Comment: st0ph - Thank you so much

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it sufficiently answered your question.

Comment: Thank you :) sorry for the delay.